# iPhone horizontal accuracy not getting above 100.00

Tags: iphone, gps, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm using CLLocationManager to get a location, and I need I within about 40-50 meters.  I have desiredAccuracy set to nearest ten meters (also tried with best).  It always comes up as 100.00.  No higher, no lower.  Don't have cell service on the phone, just going off GPS and WiFi.  iPhone 3G.  Also tried with Apple's LocateMe sample project, same results (threw in a nslog to LocateMe to check the accuracy).  Is that the highest accuracy you can get without cell service?  I feel like I used to get better.  Stumped.

Comment: Do you have wide area of clear sky directly above the device?  Even if so, you may have to wait many minutes for the device to lock onto all the satellites in view, especially with older devices such as the 3G.

Comment: What is the desired accuracy you are setting before starting updates?

Answer (score 1):

Recently Apple stop using location services of Google and stared using theirs, found locations sometimes have worse accuracy. The same you have mentioned that you have no cultural service on device, this does not allow to use AGPS (oh maybe WiFi helps a little bit). Like @hotpaw2 said, It may take some time while GPS adapter connect to satellites.